# In grammar what is the pattern of the sentence "My watch is running slow"

Tags: sentence-patterns

I am not quite sure about the pattern of sentence  "My watch is running slow" ? Is it a SVOC or something ?  Would anyone explain it in detail ?

Comment: The word *running*, is not strictly necessary in your example. That would also be the case if you were talking a clock.

Answer (score 1):

SUBJECT (“My watch”) plus intransitive VERB in present progressive tense (“is running”) plus ADVERB (“slow,” despite the lack of *-ly* suffix, which if present would alter the adverb’s meaning but not its part of speech—see below). It is the same basic sentence pattern as “He is sleeping soundly.”

A timepiece running at the exactly correct speed, but set so that it consistently indicates a time later than the relevant standard, is running *slow* but not *slowly.* Some people deliberately set inherently and otherwise accurate car-dashboard clocks and wristwatches *fast* in the usually vain hope that it will improve their own punctuality.

Comment: so do you mean "my watch is running slow" and "my watch is running slowly" have different meaning ? and how about the patterns ? I believe they are different as well

Comment: @JammyLee *Slow* usually means in this context that the watch is running behind the true time by a consistent amount, as Brian has said (at 12:00, it shows 11:55; at 14:00, it shows 13:55; and so on, always five minutes behind). *Slowly* would mean that it takes longer than an hour for the hands to move on an hour (at 12:00, it shows 11:55; at 14:00 it shows 13:45; and so on, losing more and more time all the while).

Comment: In contrasting "my watch is running slow" with "my watch is running slowly," would you say that the verb "to run" has different meanings in the two examples?  Its meaning in the first strikes me as similar to that in such sentences as "I'm running late."

Comment: They do mean the same thing, but they get to it by different routes. _My watch is running slow_ means you don't trust it; _my watch is running slowly_ refers to the workings of the machinery, but it has the same outcome -- therefore, you don't trust it.